# print only number,why it output so weird?

Tags: c

```
char* fun(char *s) {
  char buffer[50];
  int i=0;
  while(*s){
    if(isdigit(*s)){
      buffer[i++]=*s;
    }
    s++;
  }

  buffer[i]='\0';
  return buffer;
}

int main(){
  char *s="o34";
  char *p="off";

  p=fun(s);
  while(*p){
    printf("%c",p);
    p++;
  }
  //printf("%s",fun(&s[0]));
  //puts(fun(s));
  getchar();
}
```

Comment: That program doesn't look like it's going to output "so weird" anytime soon. What *does* it output?

Comment: Voting to close, no real question here.

Comment: This is a problem with your indentation.

Comment: Voting to reopen. OP has given complete program which does not give the output he/she expects(all numbers). I agree the question title is ill formed, but **we** can edit that.

Comment: @codaddict:  Nope; we don't know the expected output.  Aside from returning a pointer to a local variable, this will produce the output expected by anybody competent in C, and if that isn't what the OP expected then we need to know what that is.

Comment: @David: The title says, it's expected to print only numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the buffer as static to remove the short-term problem, but after calling the function a second time, the first reference will no longer have the old contents -- it will still point to the new contents of the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

- You are returning a pointer to the
  character array that is **local** to
  the function.
- In `printf("%c",p);` it should be
  `*p`

Answer (score 0):

One immediate problem I see is that you return a temporary buffer from fun. This causes undefined behavior. Better pass the buffer to the function or use some heap allocation (and do not forget to free it later in main).

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the address of a local array:

```
char* fun(char *s){
  char buffer[50]; 
  ...
  return buffer;
}
```